# Spring Repository solo me devuelve las queries que he creado, las nativas no

Tags: java, spring-boot

Proyecto Spring con gradle en EDI IntelliJ

He creado el controlador 'game' al que he añadido un repository, pero cuando quiero usarlo solo me devuelve las queries que yo mismo he definido, ninguna de las nativas, es decir findBy, findAll, etc.

el repositorio:

```
package com.ITAcademy.dices.repositories;

import java.util.List;

import com.ITAcademy.dices.entities.Game;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;

public interface GameRepository extends Repository<Game, Integer> {

    public List <Game> findByPlayer(Integer idPlayer);
    public boolean deleteAllByidPlayer(Integer idPlayer);

}
```

el controlador (las queries nativas que si aparecen las he escrito yo mismo) :

```
package com.ITAcademy.dices.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.ITAcademy.dices.entities.Dice;
import com.ITAcademy.dices.entities.Player;
import com.ITAcademy.dices.exceptions.PlayerNotFoundException;
import com.ITAcademy.dices.repositories.GameRepository;
import com.ITAcademy.dices.repositories.PlayerRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.ITAcademy.dices.entities.Game;

@RestController
@RequestMapping ("/dices")
public class GameController {

    @Autowired
    private final GameRepository repository;
    private final PlayerRepository playerRepository;
    private List<Game> games = new ArrayList<Game>();
    private List<Dice> dices = new ArrayList<Dice>();

    public GameController(GameRepository repository, PlayerRepository playerRepository) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.playerRepository = playerRepository;
    }

    //Get all players 
    @GetMapping("/players")
    public List <Game> getAllPlayers() {

        return repository.findAll();
    }

    //Get all games from single player
    @GetMapping("/players/{IdPlayer}/games")
    public List <Game> getPlayerGames(@PathVariable Integer idPlayer){
        try {
            return repository.findByPlayer(idPlayer);
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e){
            throw new PlayerNotFoundException(idPlayer);
        }
    }
}
```

¿Alguna sugerencia? ¿puede tratarse de algun tema de configuración?

Comment: Te falta anotar GameRepository  como @Repository

Comment: Gracias @Juan, ¿donde? ¿en el parámetro del método GameController de la clase?

Comment: Arriba de `public interface GameRepository extends Repository<Game, Integer> {`

Comment: Eclipse me da error en cuanto lo pongo